# Rails : how to render an other action in the controller, in js not in html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render, respond-to

I have two actions in my controller :

```
def find
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  render 'result', :id => @item.id
end

def result
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

The issue in that I call first the `find` action, then it calls the `result` action but in the html format. So the 'format.js` is never triggered.

How can render, at the end of the `find` action, the `result` action in the js format ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It would help if you would tag this with the programming language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your find method.

```
render 'result', :id => @item.id, :format => :js
```

Answer (score 1):

`render` method only renders views, doesn't call another action

Answer (score 1):

The bigger issue here is that you are trying to call another action, which breaks MVC pattern. Even though actions are defined as methods, think of them as something else, that cannot call other actions.

Also, please reply with code from your views that are calling/trigger these actions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

<%= render 'components/activity-slider', populer_packages: @populer_packages %>

    components/activity-slider

    <div class="slider sliderSecondary activitiesSlider">
    <% populer_packages.each do |package| %>
        <a href="#" class="sliderGrid ">
          <div class="sliderCont">
            <div class="sliderGradient"></div>
            <div class="sliderThumb">
              <div class="sliderImgWrap">
                <%= image_tag "#{package.image}", class: "img-fluid sliderImg" %>
                <div class="overlayCaptionCont">
                  <div class="overlayCaptionWrap">
                    <div class="overlayCaption">
                      <ul class="list-unstyled captionList">
                        <li>test</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```